# Edit server-side file using GWT

Tags: file, gwt, server-side

I'm new to GWT. I need to read a text file from the server, display its content in a TextArea widget, allow the user to modify it, and save the updated file back to the server. Can anyone please tell me, is it possible, and what should be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.
You can make a service to access the file (read and write) and the GWT client will easily call the service methods and update the user interface (TextArea).

Read [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html) for more details.

Also you can start right away by making a new GWT project in Eclipse and choose to generate sample code. It will generate a simple service and simple GWT page that calls the service. You can add your methods to this service to try it out as a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google App Engine server, there's no way to write file to server because of [restriction](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/java?csw=1#writefile).

To write file to server, you will need to create your own server, create a service (use Java or another server-side language) then use one of these [methods](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html) to communicate with your server.

If you still want to use GAE server (on appspot.com domain), you can use another method to store your data like Datastore or Google Cloud Storage, see [this article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/storage) for more information.